# Какое отличие между std::move и приведением к (T&&)?

Tags: c++, c++11

Скажите, в чем разница если написать `T&&` вместо `std::move`?
Вот код:

```
template<class T>
void swap(T &a, T& b)
{
    T t{ std::move(a) };
    a = (T &&)(b);
    b = std::move(t);
}
```

В данном случае так же будет вызван перемещающий оператор = (во всяком случае эффект тот же что и от `std::move`). Скажите, в чем отличие от варианта строкой ниже с `std::move`?

Comment: Ну, в определенном смысле это так и есть - например, в VC++ 2015

    `template<class _Ty> inline
     constexpr typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&&
      move(_Ty&& _Arg) _NOEXCEPT
     { // forward _Arg as movable
     return (static_cast<typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&&>(_Arg));
     }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно Стандарту языка шаблонная функция `std::move(T&& t)` [возвращает](http://eel.is/c++draft/forward#5):

```
static_­cast<remove_­reference_­t<T>&&>(t)
```

Т.е. пока шаблонная функция имеет `T&` в сигнатуре - разницы Вы не увидите. Но если функция будет принимать `T&&` аргумент, то результат уже будет иной:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
void fr(T& a) {
    std::cout << "&  " << std::is_same_v<decltype(std::move(a)), decltype((T&&)(a))> << "\n";
}

template<class T>
void frr(T&& a) {
    std::cout << "&& " << std::is_same_v<decltype(std::move(a)), decltype((T&&)(a))> << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    fr(i);
    frr(i);
}
```

[Вывод](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RFzoJqCC0pIByAqH):

> ```
> &  1    
> && 0
> ```

Происходит это потому, что для `frr` тип `T` выводится как `int&`, и запись вида `T&&` [превращается](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html) в `int&&&`, что в свою очередь снова даёт `int&`, а не `int&&`.

Мой код использует конструкции из c++17, поэтому если нужно, чтобы он собирался в c++11 надо заменить `std::is_same_v<T1, T2>` на `std::is_same<T1, T2>::value`.