# Передача объекта в качестве аргумента функции по умолчанию по ссылке

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли реализовать следующий функционал:

У меня есть функция, которая рекурсивно вызывает сама себя и передает себе в качестве параметра вектор, который затем заполняется в теле функции, при этом при первом вызове функции данный параметр не указывается и берется по умолчанию:

```
void func(int level, std::vector<int> vec = { 0 }) {
    if (level < 0)
        return;

    vec.push_back(level);

    func(level - 1, vec);
}
```

Я не хотел бы каждый раз создавать новый вектор - это затраты памяти и времени (что более критично), поэтому хотел бы передавать вектор по ссылке:

```
void func(int level, std::vector<int>& vec = { 0 }) {
...
}
```

Чтобы это работало, вектор надо делать константным, что меня не устраивает, так как для изменения вектора опять надо делать копирование:

```
void func(int level, const std::vector<int>& vec = { 0 }) {
    if (level < 0)
        return;

    std::vector<int> vec2(vec);
    vec2.push_back(level);

    func(level - 1, vec2);
}
```

Конечно, всегда остаётся возможность явно указывать вектор перед первым вызовом функции:

```
std::vector<int> vec = { 0 };
func(10, vec);
```

но так бы делать не хотелось, потому что данный вектор нужен исключительно внутри рекурсивной функции.

Подскажите, можно ли вообще реализовать этот замысел - при первом вызове никакой вектор не указывается, а берется из параметра по умолчанию, а во всех следующих вызовов используется старый вектор без каких-то дополнительных копирований и пересозданий.

**P.S.**

И не хотелось бы извратов в лоб по типу:

```
void func(int level, std::vector<int>* vec = new std::vector<int>({ 0 })) {
    if (level < 0)
        return;

    vec->push_back(level);

    func(level - 1, vec);
}
```

Хотя это, конечно, один из выходов, но как-то по ссылкам работать с объектами приятнее.

Comment: Ну а кто мешает сделать первой строкой `vector<int>&v = *vec` и работать со ссылкой? :) Ну, можно еще сделать вектор статическим для данной функции, например.

Comment: @Harry - вы имеете в виду первую строку в теле функции? это как раз то лишнее телодвижение от которого хотелось бы уйти, а если вы имеете в виде аргумент функции, то что это за сущность `*vec`?

Comment: Сделайте **две** функции. Одна первая делает вектор, а вторая его использует.

Comment: @AlexGlebe - это как раз гораздо сложнее, чем последний код в моем вопросе с указателем на вектор вместо ссылки - там единственная проблема, что потом память не освободить, но если вызовы не частые, то не критично

Comment: насчёт сложности не понимаю. `void func(int level){std::vector<int> vec = { 0 };func_private(level,vec);}`. И потом так : `void func_private(int level, std::vector<int>& vec){...}`. Всё равно компилятор именно так и сделает.

Comment: я вообще не понял: а зачем вам этот вектор? Вы не хотите его указывать перед вызовом и не возвращаете из функции. Какую роль он выполняет?

Comment: Вместо параметра по-умолчанию следует использовать перегрурузку.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, я просто не указывал весь код (ибо большой, да и смысла нет) - по сути функция вызывается рекурсивно, проверяются условия, дальше моет быть откат рекурсий на несколько этапов назад и новые рекурсии с другими условиями на несколько этапов вперед и т.д., вектор хранит некоторые данные по этапам рекурсии и участвует в анализе, поэтому он и нужен целиком только внутри функции и не хотелось бы его создавать наружи, так как это вытаскивание функционала из функции, а это некрасиво :) и получается, что до первого вызова функции вектора нет вообще, а при последующих вызовах он есть

Comment: @user7860670, конечно функцию можно обернуть в класс и т.д., но это было бы избыточным функционалом, а я как раз хочу от этой избыточности и уйти

Comment: @AlexGlebe, это один из вариантов выхода, но по сути приходится делать обёртку над основной функцией (с основным функционалом) - `func_private`, но хотелось бы как раз не плодить лишних сущностей, если язык может предоставить такую возможность

Comment: Назовите её также `func`. Раз уж вам нужна красота.

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы была именно **одна** функция, то это приведёт к рекурсивной проверке аргументов. Вектор задан или нет. Приведёт к упадке скорости из-за бессмысленной возни.

Comment: `vec` - вы же сами написали, что аргумент функции - указатель на вектор `vec`, ну а `*vec` - ссылка на вектор, на который `vec` указывает...

Comment: @Harry, да я потом понял что вы имели в виду - т.е. оставляем в параметре указатель, а в теле работаем по ссылке

Comment: зачем оборачивать функцию в класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте rvalue ссылку, указав `&&`. Для этого при рекурсивном вызове придётся добавить `std::move`:

```
#include <vector>

void func(int level, std::vector<int>&& vec = {0}) {
    if (level < 0)
        return;

    vec.push_back(level);

    func(level - 1, std::move(vec));
}

int main() {
    func(10);
}
```

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что `std::move` никак не скажется на производительности? никакого копирования не происходит, просто l-value в r-value перейдет?

Comment: @Zhihar именно так. Можете сами убедиться заменив вектор на самописный класс с контролем вызова операций копирования, перемещения.

Comment: странно, что не сделали просто однозначного присваивания, а надо вызывать функции stl, потому что так приходится явно указывать `std::move`, подразумевая, что я знаю как устроена функция (знаю конечно, если я вызываю функцию изнутри этой же функции, но если снаружи?)

Comment: @Zhihar сигнатуру функций вы в любом случае должны знать, чтобы её вызвать. Это вовсе не внутренняя информация, а внешняя.

Comment: ну да, в общем согласен, просто передавать параметр через прослойку std::move - немного неудобно, с одной стороны && в самом языке есть, а для приведения требуется функция из библиотеки

Comment: @Zhihar `std::move` это обычный каст, то что его обернули в функцию - это исключительно для удобства использования. Каст нужен, чтобы сделать выражение xvalue. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863457/176217) можете чуть подробнее об этом почитать. А вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627258/176217) о том, что есть `std::move` внутри.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что это годится только для хвостовой рекурсии? После рекурсивного вызова `func` `vec` уже не тот?

Comment: @Mikhailo не очень понял вопрос. Что значит «уже не тот»?

Comment: Ну при перемещении объекта его старое содержимое может быть удалено?  это же не копирование? И в func пойдет скажем, вектор со 100 элементами, но даже если с ним ничего не будет там делаться, то после вызова vec может вдруг стать пустым?

Comment: @Mikhailo `std::move` это ещё не перемещение. Это лишь возможность перемещения. Если перемещающее копирование или конструирование не вызывалось, то ничего не изменится. В случае присваивания rvalue-ссылке как параметру функции, ничего такого не происходит.

Comment: Сам по себе move - да, но как при этом происходит передача в функцию? При ней не происходит перемещения? Но раз вы говорите, что нет, то тогда все в порядке.

Answer (score -2):

Вы хотите создавать объект один раз, и при каждом рекурсивном вызове функции работать именно с этим объектом. Так создайте просто статический объект внутри функции(он и создастся только при первом вызове:

```
void func(int level) {
    static std::vector<int> vec{ 0 };
    if (level < 0)
        return;
    vec.push_back(level);

    func(level - 1);
}
```

Но, как верно заметил  **Andrej Levkovitch**, зачем вам этот вектор? Вы не хотите его указывать перед вызовом и не возвращаете из функции. Какую роль он выполняет? Тут или вы сами не ясно объяснили что вам нужно, или другая причина недопонимания...

Comment: К сожалению при втором вызове функции `func` вектор не про инициализируется на `{0}`.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, да именно это и нужно - 1 раз создать и затем только использовать, но AlexGlebe дело говорит - второй раз при вызове функции будет старый вектор

Comment: а зачем при каждом вызове инициализировать нулем снова?  Вообще не вижу смысла в этом

Comment: Проблема статического объекта в том, что он будет жить всё время работы программы. Но это не главная проблема, главная в том, что функцию уже нельзя будет вызвать с номинальным состоянием вектора в дальнейшем. Т.е. функция становится по сути одноразовой.